# Are there any use cases of using jsViews/jsRender with web components as the templating engine?

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

I'm writting some web components and I'd like to use jsViews $.link functionality as my templating engine. I've been able to use $.render to replace the .innerHTML of shadowRoot cloned content but I've only been able to use $.link in the following way. Just seems "dirty" to have to add an extra div to link to. Is there a better way to do this? Are there any performance issues here?:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `<div id="todo-item-tmpl"></div>`;

class TodoItem extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        this._tmpl = $.templates('#todoItems');
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

        this._todoTmpl = this._shadowRoot.querySelector('#todo-item-tmpl');
        this._tmpl.link(this._todoTmpl, this._myDataObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a full working copy in case anyone is interested: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-components-jsviews2). Still would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach, as shown in this modified version of your sample: https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/z9wnyh5q/.

Instead of defining the templates as content of script elements, they are defined using markup strings - to keep the HTML markup for the webcomponent itself.

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <to-do-app></to-do-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

The item template can be a globally defined named template,

```
$.templates("todoItemTmpl", todoItemTmpl}  // markup string for item template
```

or can be scoped to the main template as a resource, (https://www.jsviews.com/#d.templates@tmpl-resources), for better encapsulation:

```
this._tmpl = $.templates({
  markup: todoappTmpl, // markup string
  templates: {todoItemTmpl: todoItemTmpl}  // markup string for item template
});
```

The call to `this._tmpl.link(this._wrapper, this._todos, this);` (https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvtmpllink) needs to have as first parameter an HTML element (or jQuery selector) which is the container element wrapping the rendered data-linked content. It can't be directly a document fragment (the shadow root), so you need to provide the wrapper element (and optionally also insert a style element), e.g. by the following code:

```
// Create a wrapper element
this._wrapper = document.createElement('span');

// and a style element...
this._style = document.createElement('style');
this._style.textContent = todoappStyle; // Stylesheet markup

// Both inserted under the shadow root
this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
this._shadowRoot.append(this._style, this._wrapper);

// Render and data-link
this._tmpl.link(this._wrapper, this._todos, this);
```